# EclipseのJSPのフォーマットについて

Tags: eclipse, jsp

EclipseでJSPを使っているのですが、
変なところで切れてしまい、見づらいです。

具体的に言うと以下のようなパターンです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

タグが途中で切れてしまい、大変気持ち悪いです。
もしこのフォーマットの設定の仕方がわかる方がいればよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

前提として、XML上の意味として`<li><c:out /></li>`と

```xml
<li>
    <c:out />
</li>
```

は異なります。ですのでXMLとしては画像のように`li`の開始タグと`c:out`がくっ付くのは仕方がないことです。

一方HTML上は`<li></li>`の内部の空白を無視できますので、Eclipseは`<li>`と`<c:out>`の改行を除去する動作になっています。これを防ぐには*HTMLエディター*の*インライン要素*から`li`を削除すればよいです。

なおHTMLエディターの設定で属性単位の改行と最終カッコの位置合わせを有効にすると

```xml
<li
    id="..."
    class="..."
><c:out /></li>
```

のようにフォーマットされます。ただし属性が1つの場合は効果がありません。